# Getting PDF create error while running cucumber scenarios parallel in multiple browser

Tags: pdfbox, selenium-extent-report

Feb 15, 2024 1:43:05 PM tech.grasshopper.pdf.PDFCucumberReport collectReportConfiguration
INFO: PDF report configuration YAML file not found. Using default settings.
Feb 15, 2024 1:43:07 PM tech.grasshopper.pdf.PDFCucumberReport createReport
SEVERE: An exception occurred
java.io.IOException: The TrueType font null does not contain a 'cmap' table
at org.apache.fontbox.ttf.TrueTypeFont.getUnicodeCmapImpl(TrueTypeFont.java:562)
at org.apache.fontbox.ttf.TrueTypeFont.getUnicodeCmapLookup(TrueTypeFont.java:542)
at org.apache.fontbox.ttf.TrueTypeFont.getUnicodeCmapLookup(TrueTypeFont.java:528)
at org.apache.fontbox.ttf.TTFSubsetter.(TTFSubsetter.java:90)
at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.TrueTypeEmbedder.subset(TrueTypeEmbedder.java:347)
at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDType0Font.subset(PDType0Font.java:263)
at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument.save(PDDocument.java:1369)
at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument.save(PDDocument.java:1344)
at tech.grasshopper.pdf.PDFCucumberReport.createReport(PDFCucumberReport.java:133)
at tech.grasshopper.pdf.extent.ExtentPDFCucumberReporter.flush(ExtentPDFCucumberReporter.java:95)

Comment: org.apache version is 3.14 @Tilman

Comment: Such a PDFBox version doesn't exist. The latest 3.0 version is 3.0.1.

Comment: Looking closer at the stack trace, I think your font is the problem. Either this isn't a TrueType font or it's missing the cmap table, which is needed.

Comment: This is an Selenium Cucumber Framework. When I run only one Test Class file, PDF is getting created fine. But as soon as second test class runs, getting this error.

Comment: Maybe find out whether the checksum of that font file stays the same.